# ios - crashing when I try to make a segue

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection

[image][image]I have a controller that executes ok, but at the end of it, when it tries do a segue to another screen, I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<UpdateController: 0xa09bb10>) has no segue with identifier 'HomeSegue''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x247a012 0x1f6fe7e 0x15a0492 0xafd6 0xfbc5c8 0xf2402a 0xef1d23 0xef1a34 0xf7e301 0x20e253f 0x20f4014 0x20e52e8 0x20e4fcb 0x95a58b24 0x95a5a6fe)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

And I actually did make the segue that I am trying to reference, but for some reason I still get the crash.

This is how I try to do the segue after a remote server call:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
           ...
                             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomeSegue" sender:self];
```

Thanks for advice!

Comment: @jrturton how should I show it? A screen shot? Or some part of the utilities?

Comment: btw should it be push, modal or custom? I have push.

Comment: Push if you're in a navigation controller, modal otherwise (custom is more advanced...)

Comment: @jrhurton I just uploaded two images. I had push before, and now tried modal and it doesn't work either.

Comment: And both of the controllers are UIWebView controllers.

Comment: Hmm, you've got some segue spaghetti going on but it does look like the segue is set up properly. I'm not sure you want a segue if you're just returning to a previous view controller, though, as this will create a new instance of the destination view controller.

Comment: I think it is not an issue with the segue. I think its some thread lockup thing. Not sure.